# which libraries to use for programming a GUI in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to start programming a new application in C# oder VB with 
Visual Studio Code. 
Is it possible to program a GUI for my app in VS-Code and which libraries to use?

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio Code does not provide UI designing by itself. I have not seen any suitable extension to convert UI design into code, for VS-Code. How ever  I think this is a [good discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38169500/how-can-i-develop-cross-platform-gui-application-using-net-core) (*How can I develop cross-platform GUI application using .Net Core*) about your second question:

> Is it possible to program a GUI for my app in VS-Code and which
>   libraries to use

Comment: The good discussion has been removed for reasons of moderation. :-/

Answer (score 0):

The C# support in VS Code is optimized for cross-platform .NET Core development. And you can't build applications like Winforms, WPF or Silverlight on .Net Core. They're gone!

Comment: OK I understand, but what do you mean by saying "They're gone"?

Comment: They're gone from .Net Core.

Comment: I was able to build a .Net 4.72 console application using Visual Studio Code.  I am looking for a free tool to build a GUI application.  I am not able to use the Visual Studio Community version because of its license and the fact that I work for a large company.